# How to run a background video in Android activity?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-videoview

I want to implement a background video in the main activity of my App. Initially, I tried adding this video as a normal video using VideoView, but there was no setting to make it cover the entire screen, so I tried adding the same using surface view, but there is some issue. The App stops as soon as it starts.

Following is my code:-

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView=null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);


        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);





    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.introduction);

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(String.valueOf(video));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get the dimensions of the video
        int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

        //Get the width of the screen
        int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
        lp.width = screenWidth;

        //Set the height of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video
        //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
        lp.height = (int) (((float)videoHeight / (float)videoWidth) * (float)screenWidth);

        //Commit the layout parameters
        mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        //Start video
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        mp.start();

        mp.setDisplay(holder);



    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }
}
```

**Following are the logs of the same:-**

> 2019-06-12 18:38:16.128 4261-4261/? I/art: Not late-enabling
>   -Xcheck:jni (already on) 2019-06-12 18:38:16.129 4261-4261/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86 2019-06-12
>   18:38:16.504 4261-4261/com.example.liveinbliss W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.liveinbliss-1/lib/x86
>   2019-06-12 18:38:16.517 4261-4261/com.example.liveinbliss
>   I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process 2019-06-12
>   18:38:16.647 4261-4261/com.example.liveinbliss D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM
>
> ```
> --------- beginning of crash 2019-06-12 18:38:16.647 4261-4261/com.example.liveinbliss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> ```
>
> main
>       Process: com.example.liveinbliss, PID: 4261
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.liveinbliss/com.example.liveinbliss.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.liveinbliss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>
> ```
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.perf); 
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.raw.introduction);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);


        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.introduction);

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(String.valueOf(video));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get the dimensions of the video
        int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

        //Get the width of the screen
        int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
        lp.width = screenWidth;

        //Set the height of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video
        //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
        lp.height = (int) (((float)videoHeight / (float)videoWidth) * (float)screenWidth);

        //Commit the layout parameters
        mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        //Start video
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        mp.start();

        mp.setDisplay(holder);



    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }
}
```